# How to edit different number values in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I store some kind of user actions X in my database. If an user does another action Y, the field 'New_actions' is count by 1. So for example:

```
User does action X at 19:07
User does action Y at 19:08
User does action Y at 19:08
User does action X at 19:10
User does action Y at 19:12
```

Now I have the next values in my database:

```
X_actions --- Time --- New_actions
Name1 - 19:07 - 3
Name2 - 19:10 - 1
```

That means that action Y was done two times after Name1 and one time after Name2. I hope you understand me. But I have a question about that. Every hour 2 actions should be removed. The first time it shouldn't be a problem: The 'New_actions' field in Name1 should be edited to 1, but how can I make a script that the second time Name1 should be edited to 0, and Name2 also?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding your specific question. If you draw table #1 (columns & rows) of the data before the action and table #2 after the action, you will likely get a very quick answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean: The SQL should edit the first row, but if the value in the field 'New_actions' reach the 0, it should edit the values in the second row. And if that reach (or is already) 0, the script should edit the value in row 3. Hope you understand me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @remove := 2;

UPDATE my_table
SET New_actions =
   IF( New_actions >= @remove, 
       (@remove := 0)  + New_actions - @remove,
       IF(@remove := @remove - New_actions, 0, 0) )
WHERE New_actions <> 0
ORDER BY my_table.Time;
```

Used an INT Time column to simplify things, here is the result of executing above block three times:

```
+------+-------------+
| Time | New_actions |
+------+-------------+
|    1 |           3 |
|    2 |           3 |
|    3 |           3 |
+------+-------------+
+------+-------------+
|    1 |           1 |
|    2 |           3 |
|    3 |           3 |
+------+-------------+
+------+-------------+
|    1 |           0 |
|    2 |           2 |
|    3 |           3 |
+------+-------------+
+------+-------------+
|    1 |           0 |
|    2 |           0 |
|    3 |           3 |
+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to do stored procedure :)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/stored-procedures.html

Comment: I think I don't understand how I can use this;-( Can you help me please? Thanks;-)

Comment: You can create a stored procedure AddActions(Type [x/y]) which do the job (calculate the number of actions and stuffs...). Moreover you should add a Date column and filter the row which are more than 2 hours old.

Comment: Yes, but that's the problem, it's not with time. The SQL should edit the first row, but if the value in the field 'New_actions' reach the 0, it should edit the values in the second row. And if that reach (or is already) 0, the script should edit the value in row 3, and so further. Hope you understand me;-) (Or I don't understand you;-)

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you intend to do, but i'm pretty sure you can do it using stored procedure and perhaps cursor :). It worth learning it anyway :)